pandas group by unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'
measure_over_time = (df.groupby(['STORE_NBR', 'YEARMONTH'])
                    .agg(
                    total_sales= ('TOT_SALES', 'sum'),
                    number_customer = ('LYLTY_CARD_NBR', 'nunique'),
                    txn_per_customer = ('TXN_ID','nunique') / df['LYLTY_CARD_NBR'].nunique(),
                    chips_per_txn = ('PROD_QTY', 'sum')/ df['TXN_ID'].unique(),
                    avg_unit_price = ('TOT_SALES','sum')/df['PROD_QTY'].sum()
                    )
                     .reset_index()
                     .sort_values(by = ['STORE_NBR', 'YEARMONTH']))

getting error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int' i am not sure how to fix this
I have tried many ways but, not find suitable answer

The agg method accepts a dictionary of new columns as keys and a tuple as values, but you are trying to perform the division operation directly inside the agg, which is obviously wrong. You have to perform those operations separately. I don't know exactly what you are trying to do. Please add more details, desired behavior, and results, and a minimal reproducible example to your question.

The error occurs because df['LYLTY_CARD_NBR'].nunique() and df['TXN_ID'].unique() return tuples instead of individual values, and Python doesn't allow division of a tuple by an integer.
We can handle this by,

Firstly, perform the aggregation of the necessary columns.
Then, calculate the additional(such as txn_per_customer, chips_per_txn, and avg_unit_price) outside of agg() using the aggregated values.
Lastly, sort the resulting data.

updated code,
measure_over_time = (df.groupby(['STORE_NBR', 'YEARMONTH'])
                     .agg(
                         total_sales=('TOT_SALES', 'sum'),
                         number_customer=('LYLTY_CARD_NBR', 'nunique'),
                         total_txns=('TXN_ID', 'nunique'),
                         total_chips=('PROD_QTY', 'sum')
                     )
                     .reset_index())

measure_over_time['txn_per_customer'] = measure_over_time['total_txns'] / measure_over_time['number_customer']
measure_over_time['chips_per_txn'] = measure_over_time['total_chips'] / measure_over_time['total_txns']
measure_over_time['avg_unit_price'] = measure_over_time['total_sales'] / measure_over_time['total_chips']


measure_over_time = measure_over_time.sort_values(by=['STORE_NBR', 'YEARMONTH'])

